# Auto non-type template parameter with user defined types

Tags: c++, templates, c++17

In this [video](https://youtu.be/LvwXJjRQfHk?t=1655) at *27:35* **Bryce Lelbach** gives the following example:

```
template<auto... Dims>
struct dimensions {};

struct dynamic_extent {};
constexpr dynamic_extent dyn = {};

dimensions<64, dyn, 32> d;
```

This code does not compile. GCC complains:

```
<source>:8:27: error: 'struct dynamic_extent' is not a valid type for a template non-type parameter
     dimensions<64, dyn, 32> d;
                           ^
```

Clang complains:

```
<source>:8:20: error: a non-type template parameter cannot have type 'dynamic_extent'
    dimensions<64, dyn, 32> d;
                   ^
<source>:2:22: note: template parameter is declared here
    template<auto... Dims>
                     ^
```

Is his example simply wrong (that's strange because he refers to a library where this idea is used) or I do not get something?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That example is wrong. This does not work in C++17. [Non-type template parameters](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_parameters) must be one of:

> - `std::nullptr_t`
> - integral type
> - lvalue reference type (to object or to function)
> - pointer type (to object or to function)
> - pointer to member type (to member object or to member function)
> - enumeration type

Arbitrary class types are not in this list.

---

Note that it would work to use an enum as the tag type:

```
template<auto... Dims>
struct dimensions {};

enum class dynamic_extent {};
constexpr dynamic_extent dyn = {};

dimensions<64, dyn, 32> d;
```

Answer (score 10):

Yes, his example is wrong.

Non-type template parameters cannot have class type until [P0732](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p0732r1.pdf), which is a C++20 feature. And even in C++20, this would *still* be ill-formed because in order to opt-in to use `dyn` as a non-type template parameter, you need:

```
struct dynamic_extent {
    auto operator<=>(dynamic_extent ) = default;
};
```

At that point, it'll work.

---

I assume what he meant was:

```
dimensions<64, &dyn, 32> d;
//             ^^^^
```

Passing that pointer is fine - pointers are acceptable non-type template parameters in C++17 (and way earlier), as long as they meet some other requirements - which `dyn` does.